# How to generate JS from the C#.NET code

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, asp.net

Some time ago (like 3 or 4 years) I heard about ability to generate JavaScript (client) code based on C#.NET source code. I don't remember details, probably that was for validation purposes only...

If you know something about that, could you please remind?

Thanks a lot.

P.S. Any thoughts are welcome.

Comment: I think Microsoft decided to invest in SilverLight instead of taking it to market.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know of two such projects. They compile C# code into client-side JavaScript.

- **SharpKit** - http://sharpkit.net/
- **Script#** - http://projects.nikhilk.net/ScriptSharp

Comment: Script# is now here: https://github.com/NikhilK/scriptsharp
and there is Bridge.NET: https://bridge.net/

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're talking about the [Script#](http://projects.nikhilk.net/ScriptSharp) project.

It allows you to compile a sub-set of C# into JavaScript.

Answer (score -1):

For validation purposes, it may be that you saw something like xVal http://xvalwebforms.codeplex.com/.

I believe that MVC2 comes with something like this baked in.